# Using an ActionLink on my controller for accessing an external url

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working on a VS2012 ASP.NET MVC solution.

If I need to access an external url I know I can proceed like this:

```
<a href="http://www.myurl.com" target="_blank">Click me</a>
```

Is it possible to use an ActionLink in place of a classic anchor tag?

Something like:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Click me", "MyAction", "MyController", null, new { target="_blank" });
```

If this is feasable, what do I have to code inside the Action of the Controller to open an external url?

Thanks.

Comment: is there any point doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActionLink wont work in your case since it doesnt support absolute urls. You can implement a new extension:

```
public static class URLLinkHelper
{
    public static MvcHtmlString URLLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string url)
    {
        TagBuilder tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("a");
        tagBuilder.Attributes["href"] = url;
        tagBuilder.InnerHtml = linkText;
        return new MvcHtmlString(tagBuilder.ToString());
    }
}
```

Add a reference of the namespace of this class in your view.

```
@Html.URLLink("Link to yahoo", "http://yahoo.com")
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. Very instructive.

Comment: @Bronzato hope it answers your question